# Is there a faster way to recover images from a large 2-D array using vectorized operations in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have large 2-D array (typically 0.5 to 2GB) of dimension of n x 1008. This array contains the several images and the values in the array are actually the pixel value. Basically what is done to recover these images is as follow

1. Start iterating over the array.
2. Take the first 260 rows i.e you will have 260*1008=262080 values.
3. For the 261st row only take the first 64 values(the rest values in that row are junk). Thus now we have 262144 pixel values.
4. Dump all these values in a 1-D array say dump and do np.reshape(dump, (512,512))) to obtain the image. Notice that 512x512=262144
5. Repeat the same thing starting from 262nd row again.

This is my solution

```
counter=0
dump=np.array([], dtype=np.uint16)
#pixelDat is the array shaped n x 1008 containing the pixel values
for j in xrange(len(pixelDat)):
    #Check if it is the last row for a particular image
    if(j == (260*(counter+1)+ counter)):
        counter += 1
        dump=np.append(dump, pixelDat[j][:64])
        #Reshape dump to form the image and write it to a fits file
        hdu = fits.PrimaryHDU(np.reshape(dump, (512,512)))
        hdu.writeto('img'+str("{0:0>4}".format(counter))+'.fits', clobber=True)
        #Clear dump to enable formation of next image
        dump=np.array([], dtype=np.uint16)
    else:
        dump=np.append(dump, pixelDat[j])
```

I have been wondering if there is a way to speed up this whole process. The first thing that came to my mind is using vectorized numpy operations. However I am not very sure how to apply it in this case.

P.S: Do not worry about the fits and hdu part. Its just creating a .fits file for my image.

Comment: Is `pixelDat` a `numpy` array?

Comment: @PaulPanzer  pixelDat is a numpy array

Comment: I've given it a try, only the cutting up bit, no fits. Let me know whether it works for you.

Comment: Repeated `np.append` is slow.  It is better to `alist.append(...)`, and then build `dump = np.array(alist,...)` once.

Comment: @hpaulj Okay I will give that a try. Do you think writing the same thing in Cython will help?

Comment: Too much array and list indexing to be a good `cython` candidate.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an attempt using flattening and `np.split`. It avoids copying data.

```
def chop_up(pixelDat):
    sh = pixelDat.shape
    try:
        # since the array is large we do not want a copy
        # the next line will succeed only if we can reshape in-place
        pixelDat.shape = -1
    except:
        return False # user must resort to other method
    N = len(pixelDat)
    split = (np.arange(0, N, 261*1008)[:, None] + (0, 512*512)).ravel()[1:]
    if split[-1] > N:
       split = split[:-2]
    result = [x.reshape(512,512) for x in np.split(pixelDat, split) if len(x) == 512*512]
    pixelDat.shape = sh
    return result
```

Comment: I dont understand some places of your code.

split = (np.arange(0, N, 261*1008)[:, None] + (0, 512*512)).ravel()[1:]  always gives the same value no mattter what the value of N is. So why not hard code it?

pixelDat.shape = sh (what do you need this line for? Seems like it has no use because we are returning the result only)

Comment: @AnirbanDutta It doesn't, I just checked. Did you try large enough values of N? Like 1,000,000 against 2,000,000? Assigning the shape like that changes it in-place, meaning that any variable that references the object will see the change. Try `A=np.arange(4);B=A;B.shape=2,2;A`

Comment: Oh my bad..I forgot my array is very large.. The rest seems okay. Should work much faster now.

Comment: `np.split` iterates on the `split` list, doing something like `[pixelDat[i:j, ;] for i,j in zip(starts, stops)]`.  That is successively  takes slices of the array.  You might save a bit of time by doing that split and the reshape in one iteration.  On the other hand it might just make the code messier.

Comment: @hpaulj thanks, that is good to know. I had developed a habit of bending over backwards in order to be able to use the "fast" `split` over a list comprehension. --- In this particular case it is probably not worth fiddling. How many chunks of 250K elements can there be?